# Tangent space over non-algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm considering if usual definition of tangent space for an affine algebra works when $k$ is not algebraically closed.

Suppose that $A := k[X_1, \ldots, X_n] / \mathfrak{a}$ is an integral $k$-algebra and $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal with residue field $k(\mathfrak{m}) := A / \mathfrak{m}$ which is an algebraic field extension of $k$. I would like to show that there is a canonical isomorphism of $k(\mathfrak{m})$-vector spaces

$$ \operatorname{Der}_k(A, k(\mathfrak{m})) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{k(\mathfrak{m})}(\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2, k(\mathfrak{m})) $$

where the left hand side is the collection of $k(\mathfrak{m})$-linear derivations.

I can show this in the case $k(\mathfrak{m}) = k$ in the usual way, but struggling to do it in general. On the other hand I can also show that the left hand side has roughly the right dimension with the following (standard) argument

$$ \dim_{k(\mathfrak{m})} \operatorname{Der}_k(A,k(\mathfrak{m})) = n - \operatorname{rk}_{k(\mathfrak{m})} \left( \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial X_j} + \mathfrak{m} \right) \geq  n - \operatorname{rk}_{\operatorname{Frac}(A)} \left( \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial X_j} \right) = \dim A$$

Question: Is the left hand side of the proposed isomorphism a sensible definition of tangent space ?

Comment: Your definition only works if $k$ is a perfect field. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B2E

Comment: @DamianRössler I posted a solution based on this and some other references, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a reasonable solution, following Hartshorne II Ex 8.1 and Matsumura Commutative Algebra Proposition 28.I.

Firstly we may observe that

$$ \operatorname{Der}_k(A, k(\mathfrak{m})) \cong \operatorname{Der}_k(A / \mathfrak{m}^2, k(\mathfrak{m})) $$

as derivations annihilate $\mathfrak{m}^2$. When $k(\mathfrak{m}) = k$ (e.g. $k$ algebraically closed or $\mathfrak{m}$ a $k$-rational point) then we may decompose

$$ A / \mathfrak{m}^2 := k(\mathfrak{m}) \oplus \mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2 $$

which allows us to show the mapping is surjective and injective. When $k(\mathfrak{m}) / k$ is non-trivial but separable (and finite) then we may use ``formal smoothness'' of this extension (Prop 28.I Matsumura) to split the canonical map

$$ A / \mathfrak{m}^2 \rightarrow k(\mathfrak{m}) $$

and obtain the direct sum. We may show that a derivation annihilates $k(\mathfrak{m})$ and then the correspondence follows easily. One has to be careful about the $k$-linearity of the derivations; however since the subring $k(\mathfrak{m}) / k$ of $A$ is separable a derivation vanishes on $k$ if and only if it vanishes on $k(\mathfrak{m})$, using a standard result.

Comment: Yes this is fine. To get the splitting, you may apply 28.3 (ii) in Matsumura (which follows from 28.1). Note that a more conceptual argument uses the cotangent complex, as in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B2E.

Comment: Right I see Matsumura Commutative Ring Theory has more explicit version of the result. Trying to digest the stacks version.